# Python tkinter GUI: which widget to use for having copyable text

Tags: python, user-interface, text, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to designing GUIs in python and have a query:

Is there a way to have a label or any other widget with copyable text. I want to provide help section within GUI which will contain a sample xml to be given as input, I want user to be able to copy that xml.

I don't want that information to go away if user cuts that information, so I am not using a entry widget with pre-filled data.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `text` widget in disabled state.

There is no insertion cursor in this state, but the text may still be selected and copied (but not modified).